# BASH script updating user permissions

Tags: bash, if-statement, chmod

I am writing a bash script that will change user permissions based on user input.

So far I take in the information from the user like so:

```
read -p 'Enter a filename: ' filename
read -p 'Do you want to allow read permission? ' allowRead
read -p 'Do you want to allow write permission? ' allowWrite
read -p 'Do you want to allow execute permission? ' allowExecute
```

I had thought about creating a series of nested if else statements, checking whether the values of the allowX variables where either Yyes or Nno and taking appropriate action there, but I realized this might get a bit convoluted.  Is there a way to update the permissions of a file, using `chmod` based on the input I have taken in from the user without creating an absurdly long series of if else statements?

Comment: ...yes? I mean, where's the specific question here? You haven't shown us why anyone would think that an "absurdly long list of `if` statements" *would* be needed otherwise. (You've *told* us that you think that, but haven't *shown* us *why* you think it).

Comment: Hint: `chmod "u=${allowRead+r}${allowWrite+w}${allowExecute+x}" filename` is all that's needed if the named variables are nonempty for a true answer but empty for a false one.

Comment: ...and of course you can also use bitwise arithmetic to build up a result one bit at a time.

Comment: `[[ $allowRead = [yY]* ]] && (( perm |= 4 )); [[ $allowWrite = [yY]* ]] && (( perm |= 2 )); [[ $allowExecute = [yY]* ]] && (( perm |= 1 ))`, etc. will also build up a numeric `perm` value.

Comment: ...but that's not an answer to a specific question that's been asked, because I don't see any specific question here at all.